Determine if the multivariate function is continuous
I am trying to determine if this function:
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
    \frac{x^2 - y^2}{e^{x+y}-1},  &\text{if $x + y \neq 0$} \\ 
    x - y, &\text{if $x + y = 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Is continuous in all points $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x + y = 0$. I know that we can determine if a function is continuous in $a$ if:
$$
\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)
$$
So I am trying to see if, for all points in the set described above, that:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,-a)}f(x,y) = f(a,-a)
$$
But, since we have to use the above equation, I end up in a $\frac00$ indeterminate. I don't know what to do now. Any help?

We have $$ \frac{x^2-y^2}{e^{x+y}-1}=(x-y)\left( \frac{e^{x+y}-e^0}{(x+y)-0}\right)^{-1}.$$ Try to finish from here.

Using this, I can get the multiplication of both limits, correct? But, to get to the fundamental limit on the second term I'd have to use a change of variables (say, $u = x - a$ and $v = y + a$).
Am I on the correct path here?

You can use a change of variables or you can just note that if $(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow (a,-a)$, then $x_n+y_n \rightarrow a+(-a)= 0$.

But then wouldn't I just end up with the same $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate form on the second term?

No, we have $\frac{e^h-e^0}{h-0}\rightarrow e^0= 1$ for $h\rightarrow 0$. It's just the difference quotient of the exponential function (i.e. we get the derivative of $e^x$ for $x=0$).

Got it! Thank you for the help!

You're welcome. I suggest you spell your insight out as an answer below. This would help you organize your thoughts, gives the community the opportunity to suggest improvements and might help people with a similar question in the future.

Also some people get cranky if questions get answered in the comments as the question keeps showing up on the unanswered list.

As an alternative to the fine method suggested in the comments, we can proceed also as follows using that eventuality as $x+y\to 0$
$$1+x+y\le e^{x+y}\le 1+x+y+(x+y)^2$$
therefore
$$1\le \frac{e^{x+y}-1}{x+y}\le 1+x+y$$
As you noticed to show continuity $x+y\to 0$ we need to show that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,-a)}f(x,y) = f(a,-a)$$
which is true indeed we have
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,-a)} \frac{x+y}{e^{x+y}-1}(x-y)=1\cdot 2a )=f(a,-a)$$

Your first statement is misleading. $e^{x+y}\le 1+x+y+(x+y)^2$ holds if $x+y$ is sufficiently small, but it does not hold in general.

@MartinR yes of course I mean eventually, I add that fact I was assuming implicitly. Thanks

An idea: fix $\;y\;$ and then do the limit $\;x\to -y\;$ and use L'Hospital:
$$\lim_{x\to -y}\frac{x^2-y^2}{e^{x+y}-1}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to-y}\frac{2x}{e^{x+y}}=\frac{-2y}{e^0}=-2y$$
and of course $\;-2y=x-y\;$ if $\;x+y=0\iff x=-y\;$

I don't get why we can do this. I see that it gets us the answer but why are we able to just fix $y$ like this?
